# Passing default parameters to functions as default parameters

Tags: ocaml, conventions, optional-parameters, default-arguments

I have a number of functions with default parameters, eg.

```
let h_foo a b = a * b
let foo ?(f_heuristic=h_foo) a b = f_heuristic a b

(* caller of foo where may want to change `f_heuristic` *)
let fn ?(f=foo) a b =
  f a b

fn 5 6                                            (* => 30 *)
```

But, I want to be able to call the wrapper functions with different values of the defaults for the defaults of the wrapper function.  I run into the following error, that confuses me, and I don't know how to resolve.

```
fn ~f:(fun a b -> a + b) 5 6
(* Line 1, characters 6-24:
 * Error: This function should have type
 *          ?f_heuristic:(int -> int -> int) -> int -> int -> int
 *        but its first argument is not labelled *)
```

Is this possible in Ocaml, or is it the wrong approach?
ThankS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let fn ?(f=(foo : int -> int -> int)) a b = f a b;;
```

The problem is the type for the optional argument `f` in your code is inferred to be the type of `foo` which has an optional argument. By changing the default value to have the type you want, you can give `fn` the type you want too.